# WP API V2: Query posts by ACF

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, advanced-custom-fields, wp-api

I would like to query my posts by filtering for a custom meta added with Advanced Custom Fields. It's a boolean meta, so every post will have something like:

> GET http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

```
{
  ...
  "acf" : {
    "highlight" : true
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm not able to filter by this meta value, even if I exposed meta_key and meta_value to the REST API in `function.php`:

```
function my_add_meta_vars ($current_vars) {
    $current_vars = array_merge ($current_vars, array ('meta_key', 'meta_value'));
    return $current_vars;
}
add_filter ('rest_query_vars', 'my_add_meta_vars');
```

But if I try:

> GET
>   http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[meta_key]=highlight&filter[meta_value]=true

I see all the posts as if the filter is ignored.

Comment: The filter parameter was disabled when the REST API was merged into WP Core. You can add it back with the rest-filter plugin. Here's the article: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#what-happened-to-the-filter-query-parameter And here's the link to the filter plugin: https://github.com/wp-api/rest-filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this solved with this customization:

```
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', function ( $valid_vars ) {
    return array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'highlight', 'meta_query' ) );
} );
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', function( $args, $request ) {
    $highlight   = $request->get_param( 'highlight' );

    if ( ! empty( $highlight ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'highlight',
                'value'   => $highlight,
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        );      
    }

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

And do a query in this way (highlight is acf boolean)

> GET /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?highlight=1

Comment: How would this code look if only one object is expected as a response, instead of an array?